# IIS 6 Proxy Pass/Proxy Reverse Pass

Tags: proxy, iis-6

I have a request to forward a a directory on our website to another partner website we will be working with.  For example I would like to forward requests to another site but keep the URL the same.

So in a nutshell:

http://www.test.com/folder

will forward to

100.100.104.118/folder

but will keep the original URL of http://www.test.com/folder.  Hope that makes sense.  This site is on Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really sure this is the site for that. I'm not downvoting nor suggesting closing or moving, but I suggest you also look at [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) (another site of the Stack Exchange, similar to this one).